# How to say that action has changed another resource in a REST API?

Tags: rest

I was wondering how in a REST API (or REST like API) one should deal with a resource modification that have impact on an other resource.

For the sake of clarity I'll take the example of a bill. A bill contains several lines and each line have an amount. The bill also have a property stating the total amount, which is the sum of all lines' amount.

A representation of a bill using JSON could be :

```
{
    id: 156,
    amount: 12,
    lines: [
        1: {
            label : 'Item 1'
            amount: 8
       }
       2: {
            label: 'Item 2',
            amount: 4
        }
    ]
}
```

What is a the best way to update a line and be informed the bill amount has changed ?

I came up with some ideas, they all have advantages and drawbacks.

**Solution 1 : Use one resource**

That solution came from that question : "Should resources have impact on other resource ?"
Answering no leads to the use of only one resource for a bill and its lines. This allows to use patch on the bill resource.
Furthermore we could argue that a bill without lines makes no sense.

Request

```
PATCH api.something.com/bills/156
{
    lines: [
        1: {
             amount: 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Or, using [RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)

```
PATCH api.something.com/bills/156
[
{ "op": "replace", "path": "/lines/1/amount", "value": 4 }
]
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Success
{
 id: 156,
 amount: 8,
 lines: [
     1: {
         label : 'Item 1'
         amount: 4
     }
     2: {
         label: 'Item 2',
         amount: 4
     }
 ]
}
```

Advantages :

- One resource
- No need to deal with embedded resources
- If line order changes (deletion or addition) we will have the new one

Drawbacks :

- Loosing the super handy POST on api.something.com/bills/156/lines for lines addition.
- Loosing the super handy DELETE/PATCH on api.something.com/bills/156/lines/1 for line deletion/modification

**Solution 2 : Call on subresource and redirect**

If we agree on using a subresource for lines one solution is to use a 303 Redirect response, as [Roy T. Fielding proposes](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Line addition

Request

```
POST api.something.com/bills/156/lines
{
    label: 'Item 156',
    amount: 10
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Location: https://api.something.com/bills/156
```

Line update

Request

```
PATCH api.something.com/bills/156/lines/
{
    amount: 5
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Location: https://api.something.com/bills/156
```

Line deletion

Request

```
DELETE api.something.com/bills/156/lines/2
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Location: https://api.something.com/bills/156
```

Drawbacks:

- Lines are part of bill and are also subresources
- Have to fetch the bill resource with the lines when a line is added, deleted, or modified
- Works only for resources we don't care that much about (subresource or without an intersting content)

Advantages :

- Use of post, put and delete

**Solution 3 : Use links**

Third option is to use links, using [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) for instance.
HAL allows to add properties to link. Introducing a hasChange property solves the problem.

A line amount update would works like this :

Request

```
PATCH api.something.com/bills/156/lines/1
{
    amount: 5
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Success
{
    amount:5,
    label: "Item 1",
    "_links": {
        "bill": { 
            "href": "/bill/156",
            hasChanged: true
        }
    }
}
```

Advantages :

- Works for non subresource
- Works when several resources are updated

Drawbacks :

- Dealing with links. ([But links are a major part of REST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

I'm curious to know if someone can advise for or against one of the solutions because they all seem interesting to me.